# Issues with Threads. Trying to test a timer that utilizes threads and seem to get stuck in a loop

Tags: java, loops, timer, java-threads

My TEST creates an instance of SimpleTimer with 1000 as a milliseconds measure to delay the thread by 1 second.

```
@Test
public void testSimpleTimerAsThread() throws InterruptedException
{
    SimpleTimer st = new SimpleTimer(1000);
    st.start();
    Thread.sleep(250); 
    for(int x = 0; x<5; x++)
    {
        assertEquals(x, st.getRound());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

My METHOD

timeChanged() just updates the round number and calls for all observers to update their time.

```
public void start()
{
    for(int r = 0; r<5; r++)
    {
        try 
        {
            timeChanged();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
        }
    }
}
```

SimpleTimer extends Thread and implements an interface that doesn't really mess with this code.

When I run this i get the java assertion error saying it expected 0 but was 5 so x never incremented and the round increased by 5.

Comment: Yes for the first assert equals, x = 0 and round = 5 so assert will fail.

Comment: round = 5 with my assumption that  timeChanged(){round+1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SimpleTimer` works in the same thread as the rest, so when you call `st.start()` what happens is it goes straight there and executes everything, then the rest of your test is executed. You need to put all of your `SimpleTimer` logic in `run` method instead of `start` method and remove start method completely, Thread class already has it implemented in the right way (but keep call to `st.start()`, it's ok, that's how you start a new Thread). But even then it's not gonna work as expected, but this will actually be concurrency problem, not a mistake. I mean there is a slight possibility that it's gonna work (only sometimes, not always), because of the delays, but relying on delays it's not really a good idea.

Comment: implemented and it passes. Thank you for your knowledge and help.